# svg.js: select elements with mouse

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I am using [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) to draw a svg with several boxes like this:

[image]

The SVG contents look like this:

```
<g id="1">
  <title>Box 1</title>
  <polygon id="target_1" fill="#fdb8d4" points="70 10 100 10 100 40 70 40"/>
</g>
```

I'd like to select one or multiple boxes on mouse down, move and release, e.g. like visualized in this image:

[image]

I found the [select plugin](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.select.js) for svg.js, but it seams not to do the job.

Can someone point me into the right direction? Is there some functionality already existing or do i need to implement it from scratch?

Simple fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zgokwdqL/).

Comment: would it be possible for you to make a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes, i prepared a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zgokwdqL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a plugin called [nuSelectable](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Select-Multiple-Elements-with-Mouse-nuSelectable.html).

You can use it like so [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/pjo6v1bh/)

```
<div class="svgContainer">
  <svg height="150" width="150" class="item">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" style="fill: blue; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="150" width="150" class="item">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" style="fill: blue; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px;" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

JS initialization code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.svgContainer').nuSelectable({
    items: '.item',
    selectionClass: 'nu-selection-box',
    selectedClass: 'nu-selected',
    autoRefresh: true
  });
});
```

P.S. The selection box for some reason is not visible in the fiddle, but in chrome is visible, feel free to style it using the class `.nu-selection-box`.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but unfortunatley it does not work for my use case. I do not have several SVG elements, i only have one and want to select the polygons inside.